# TS2322 Type X | Y | Z[] is not assignable to type Z[]- Typescript

Tags: typescript, redux

I am new to Typescript and in the process of migrating my react native code base to Typescript. There is a strange error that I cannot get resolved however I tried. 
here is the reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE: MessagingState = {
conversations: [],
send: [],
read: []
};

export default function (state: MessagingState = INITIAL_STATE, action: 
UserMessagingActionTypes): MessagingState {
switch (action.type) {
    case USER_CONVERSATIONS_RECEIVED:
        return {...state, conversations: action.payload};
    case USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED:
        return {
            ...state,
            conversations: [...state.conversations, action.payload]
        };
    default:
        return state;
   }
}

export interface MessagingState {
conversations: Conversation[]
send: StompMessage[]
read: ChatMessage[]
}
```

and the actions types:

```
export interface UserConversationsReceived {
type: typeof USER_CONVERSATIONS_RECEIVED,
payload: Conversation[]
}

export interface UserConversationReceived {
type: typeof USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED,
payload: Conversation
}

export interface UserStompUnseenMessageReceived  {
type: typeof MESSAGING_ACTIONS.USER.UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED,
payload: ChatMessage
}


export const MESSAGING_ACTIONS = {
  USER:{UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED: 'UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED'}
}
export const USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED= 'USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED';
export const USER_CONVERSATIONS_RECEIVED = 'USER_CONVERSATIONS_RECEIVED';

export type UserMessagingActionTypes =
UserConversationsReceived
| UserConversationReceived
| UserStompUnseenMessageReceived;
```

I was expecting  type narrowing to kick in on my reducer, but I get the following two errors in the return statements in the reducer:

***Error:(14, 31) TS2322: Type 'Conversation | ChatMessage | Conversation[]' is not assignable to type 'Conversation[]'.
  Type 'Conversation' is missing the following properties from type 'Conversation[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.***

*Error:(18, 17) TS2322: Type '(Conversation | ChatMessage | Conversation[])[]' is not assignable to type 'Conversation[]'.
  Type 'Conversation | ChatMessage | Conversation[]' is not assignable to type 'Conversation'.
    Type 'ChatMessage' is missing the following properties from type 'Conversation': title, unreadMessages, messages*

Why Conversaion[] is not assignable to Conversation[]?

**Edit 1:**
 This piece is the culprit:

```
export const MESSAGING_ACTIONS = {
  USER:
   {UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED: 'UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED'}
}
```

When I change this to a string const like this:

```
export const UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED: 'UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED';
```

the issue gets resolved. I dont know how **typeof** is different between the two of them. They are both string. But whats going on with the compiler, I dont know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why TypeScript cannot narrow the type down in your case. I got it working here on [TypeScript Playground.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wKoGUCiAlAfQGEB5AOQDV8sBBAFQElyC8cicGqAROAXjgBE2fMXJU8tRs1btOOLgIDcAKFCRYiFOjhY6JALIAFAhjK4cZAvpxZaAcRws2Hbn0G6Dx0+cvXbNBydZbiVVcGh4JDRMXEJSSmp6JjMgl3k3IVjRBIkk8ixUuQUVZQQAGwBDVFQ4IhQAN2AoVAqYAEsUOABvCoylAF9SyuragAtW-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-L88XQzlB2QQEpWUdY5QQvYDkLNCvivV5sNw-DCKzEis3IyiRGo0t1wrBjlCYqcWOE59kC4nj4O2fiUPdJoLggABbMAMDQYBwS9OYxOAPDgAI-c7lI6Sg1kjwjBMMwcAsKwbHsRxlO4RiJ3Uj4iHGGBbOAHS4PgUjUKaWyfRHZAAyDGpeGUIyoFYzDuXsxyIWUAAfZL8s09jivw8rKpM8zLLBGzw1mYBaqcxQgA)

Beware that the type of your Actions need to be strings which are instantly assigned a value with either no type definition `export const USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED = 'USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED'` or with the specific string as type definition like this `export const USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED: 'USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED' = 'USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED'`.

```
export const USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED = 'USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED'; // Correct
export const USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED: 'USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED' = 'USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED'; // Correct
export const USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED: string = 'USER_CONVERSATION_RECEIVED'; // Wrong
```

It seems that TypeScript infers your nested property to be of type string (as you found out). If you use a const on a primitive type string, the value can never be changed - thus, the type can be narrowed down from string to 'UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED'. If you nest that inside an object, the object reference itself is always the same - but you can change properties of that object. Thus, TypeScript has to assume the type is string (and cannot narrow it down more), since it could be changed at some point (because it is not readonly by default).

A workaround would be, obviously, to not nest it. As an alternative, you can provide typescript with a more narrow type, though that would look quite verbose:

```
export const MESSAGING_ACTIONS: { 
    USER: {
        UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED: 'UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED'
    }
} = {
    USER:{
        UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED: 'UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED'
    }
}

// or with an interface

export interface MessagingActions {
    USER: {
        UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED: 'UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED'
    }
}

export const MESSAGING_ACTIONS:MessagingActions = {
    USER:{
        UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED: 'UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED'
    }
}
```

Comment: the culprit is this piece: export const MESSAGING_ACTIONS = {
USER:{UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED: 'UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED'}
}. how is typeof different here?

Comment: @BlackLog I am not entirely sure why, but TypeScript infers `UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED` to be of type `string`, if you declare it like this. You can actually see this if you change it in playground and hover over the `type: typeof MESSAGING_ACTIONS.USER.UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED` and compare that to the other types.

Comment: @BlackLog Seems after thinking about this for a bit I found the reason to why TypeScript infers the type the way it does: If you use a `const` on a primitive type string, the value can never be changed - thus, the type can be narrowed down from `string` to `'UNSEEN_MESSAGE_RECEIVED'`. If you nest that inside an object, the object reference itself is always the same - but you can change properties of that object. Thus, TypeScript has to assume the type is `string`, since it *could* be changed at some point (since it is not readonly or something).